# Center icon vertically next to text

Tags: html, css

I have tried below code to get desired output,  how to display that lock in middle of that.

I have tried so many thing, which I found on SO, but nothing helpful. 
I am not very experienced in CSS.

I want to display like this:

[image]

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.lock_image {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

hr {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0px;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.title {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-block"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/f7sA2Q/icons8_Lock_50.png" alt="icons8_Lock_50" border="0" class="lock_image"></div>
<div class="inline-block">
  <p class="title">Google Drive Integrated Email</p>
  <hr>
  <a class="mgl20" href="javascript:void(0);">xyz@gmail.com</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a wrapper around the content you had and made it a `flexbox` with vertical center alignment.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.lock_image {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

hr {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0px;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.title {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inline-block">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/f7sA2Q/icons8_Lock_50.png" alt="icons8_Lock_50" border="0" class="lock_image">
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <p class="title">Google Drive Integrated Email</p>
    <hr>
    <a class="mgl20" href="javascript:void(0);">xyz@gmail.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , that's good , i tried `display:flex` not know for the `align-item`. i will accept your asnwer when SO allow to me

Answer (score 1):

Please add `vertical-align:middle` in `inline-block` class.

```css
.inline-block{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.lock_image{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

hr{
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0px;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.title{
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-block"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/f7sA2Q/icons8_Lock_50.png" alt="icons8_Lock_50" border="0" class="lock_image"></div>
<div class="inline-block"><p class="title">Google Drive Integrated Email</p><hr>
    <a class="mgl20" href="javascript:void(0);">xyz@gmail.com</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rhulkashyap/71a9uLvy/

```css
.inline-block{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.lock_image{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

hr{
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0px;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.title{
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-block"><img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GHHKwv7.png" alt="icons8_Lock_50" border="0" class="lock_image"></div>
<div class="inline-block"><p class="title">Google Drive Integrated Email</p><hr>
    <a class="mgl20" href="javascript:void(0);">xyz@gmail.com</a>
</div>
```