# How to parallel progress bar to the center of an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS, and I have a positioning question.

Here is the current layout
[original_layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Y1o.png)

I wanna make it looks like this
[desired_layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki085.png)

```html
<div style="margin-left: 5%;">
  <div style="display: inline;">
    <img style=" width: 60px; " id="switch_img" src="../images/button_hotoff.png">
  </div>

  <div style="display: inline; padding-left: 10%;">
    <input id="heatSlider" data-slider-id='heatSliderSlider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="255" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0" />
  </div>
</div>
```

but I don't now how to move the progress bar up. Can anyone offer me any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: my bad, done. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: use `display:inline-block`. and refer this quesition. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45913028/center-icon-vertically-next-to-text

Comment: I tried, It won't work

Comment: provide a working fiddle or snippet , and use `display:inline-block`

Comment: @JINYUWU , try below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code , i just try to make img and slider in one line , instead of different different lines.:

```js
$('#heatSlider').slider();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inline-block{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="inline-block" >
   <img style=" width: 60px; " id="switch_img" 
     src="https://image.ibb.co/f7sA2Q/icons8_Lock_50.png">
 </div>
<div class="inline-block" style="padding-left:2%">
 <input id="heatSlider" data-slider-id='heatSliderSlider' 
  type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="255" data-slider-step="1" 
  data-slider-value="0" />
 </div>
</div>
```